# AutomateCollection's findAll function showing error evalute timed out maximum time

Tags: c#

Here is the code to get all tabs url for chrome. Its working sometime(if I restart VS15 or restart pc it works but not always in these case as well).

```
        Process[] procsChrome = Process.GetProcessesByName("chrome");
        string vals = "";
        foreach (Process chrome in procsChrome)
        {
            if (chrome.MainWindowHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
                continue;

            AutomationElement element = AutomationElement.FromHandle(chrome.MainWindowHandle);
            if (element == null)
                return;
            Condition conditions = new AndCondition(
                //new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.IsEnabledProperty, true),
                new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.IsControlElementProperty, true),
                //new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.IsContentElementProperty, true),
                new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.TabItem));

            AutomationElementCollection elementx = element.FindAll(TreeScope.Descendants, conditions);
            foreach (AutomationElement item in elementx)
            {
                //vals += ((ValuePattern)item.GetCurrentPattern(ValuePattern.Pattern)).Current.Value as string;
                urls += item.Current.Name + " | ";
            }                 
        }
```

in the line written below the message shows when I try to debug the value. and get AutomationElementCollection array count to 0.

> AutomationElementCollection elementx =
>   element.FindAll(TreeScope.Descendants, conditions);

But it bring accurate result sometime as well. So how can I make it persistent for always?

Here is a screenshot of when I get the result:

[image]